# php delete file with unlink()

Tags: php, fopen, unlink, fclose

I have read a lot of pages about this but I just can't get it to work.
I have a file on my server that needs to be deleted after the file has been imported.

The file is a .csv file and opened with `fopen`.

After import the file is closed with `fclose`.

Now I want to delete the file with:

```
chown($filepath, 666);

if (file_exists($filepath))
{
    if (unlink($filepath))
    {   
            echo "success";
    }
    else
    {
            echo "fail";    
    }   
}
else
{
        echo "file does not exist";
}
```

It keeps failing with `file does not exist`but I don't know why.
I use the exact same path to import

M.

Comment: What is value in `$filepath`?

Comment: What are you using in `$filepath`? Is it a relative or absolute path?

Comment: `$filepath = 'http://www.xxx.nl/files/testing.csv';`

Comment: Unlink won't work with URLs*, please use a relative or absolute path, so `/var/www/path/to/file.csv` or `./path/to/file.csv` (* there are exceptions, but generally best to use paths instead).

Comment: @Interactive can you provide original file path

Comment: Ah crap I didn't knew that. Problem solved. Thank you! I provided the absolute path to the file.

Answer (score 0):

You cant directly access the file using URL

```
$filepath = 'http://www.xxx.nl/files/testing.csv';
```

To access your file, use

```
$filepath = ./files/testing.csv
```

so file structure would be

```
- file
   - testing.csv
- index.php
```